# EntityQuery with node_access module compatibly

Tags: 8, nodes

I have installed [node_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess/releases/8.x-1.0-beta3) for maintaining access per node. I need to write a sql query using entityQuery service and display only those nodes which respect [node_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess/releases/8.x-1.0-beta3) configuration per node. I am not able to find any documentation for this. 
Currently my entityQuery is showing all results to ananymous users. Please let me know If one write query to resepct node_access module.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('type', 'article');
$nids = $query->execute();
```

Comment: The linked module is for Drupal 6.

Comment: @4k4 Oh Sorry. _corrected the link_

Comment: Given that it integrates with the core grants system, `$query->addTag('node_access');` might do it

Comment: @Clive Thanks for your reply but its not working. I had tried it earlier before posting the question